How to submit checkbox values as a string in a HTTP POST handler?
When using a REMOTE POST method to send data to a URL ... And using a checkbox field type, the data is submitted as an array.
We need to submit it as a concatenated string.
Is there a setting somewhere I don't know about, that can change how that data is submitted?
Or, can I pass the value of the checkboxes, as a token to a different field, that does get submitted, that gets converted in to a delimited string ?

Not enough info here to understand what you are asking, or even whether Drupal is the client or the server in this scenario.

I think they're asking if the data from a checkbox type can be serialized into a string in the posted data. It doesn't seem confusing. Anyway, you probably need to write some code.

If you use the tokens in the custom data, the values will be joined with a ",".

